# Is there a method in networkx to get the top 10 nodes by clustring coefficient?

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I am working on finding the top 10 nodes according to the clustering coefficient, so far I have tried this

```
clus_coef = []
for node in G.nodes():
    clus_coef.append(nx.clustering(G,node))
```

I am not sure, how to the get the top 10 nodes with their along with their coefficients ?

Answer (score 0):

You first get the clustering result `clus_coef` and then sort the dictionary based on values. Use the `Counter.most_common()` method, it'll sort the items for you. You can then return top `N` items:

```
import networkx as nx
clus_coef = nx.clustering(G)

from collections import Counter
c = Counter(clus_coef)
c.most_common(10)
```